# The correct and impact of italic mode on dot and comma

Tags: tex-core

I'm writing a report and came across this issue which is putting dot or comma inside `\textit{}`. In my case,

> by Smith \textit{et al,},~\cite{P_Cheeseman}

[image]

I have two questions: **1)** is dot affected by `textit{}`? **2)** which is better in this case about comma, should I put inside the italic mode? I know the second question has nothing to do with LaTeX, but I'm asking as a writing style.

Comment: In a partial answer to (2), [MLA says comma should not be in italics. Except sometimes.](https://style.mla.org/comma-after-italicized-element/)

Comment: [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0110.html) is also a bit indecisive.

Comment: A bit more specialized situation: In a math expression, commas are *not* italicized.  Regarding your question about the dot, yes, it may be different, but the difference is so slight that probably nobody wlll notice it.

Comment: There are typographic discussions about whether or not punctuation that directly follows italicized text should be italic as well, regardless of semantics. Some people say, they should, because the punctuation mark (take a colon for example) may stick too closely to the last letter otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically here I think it's clear that the comma is part of the (English) sentence structure and not part of the Italic insert denoting a foreign word so `\textit{et al},` is more logical (and what I'd use, if I was italicising a foreign word). Normally (or at least often) though et al. is considered an abbreviation rather than a word so `\textit{et al.}` where logically the . sticks with the word, followed if necessary by a comma outside the italic.

Typographic conventions though don't always follow logic so if this is a reference list in a journal, just do whatever the journal wants.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said "it all depends". It is a typographic style as to whether ending punctuation should be considered to be part of the italic text or as part of the main text.

A couple of thoughts:

o what if the italic text ends with an exclamation mark instead of a comma? An italic exclamation looks very different from a normal text one, but the comma is very similar in either case (and who would notice the minor differences?).

o If the differentiated text was bold instead of italic I would have thought that the punctuation should be bold, not regular.

I guess that it is a matter of style, over which many can (politly) disagree